# Tensorflow: zip over first dimension of two tensors of different shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's say I have two tensors, whose shapes are `[b, n]` and `[b, n, m]` respectively.  These can be interpreted as a batch of input vectors each of shape `[n]` and a batch of weight matrices each of shape `[n, m]`, where the batch size is `b`.  I would like to pair these up element-wise across the first dimension, so each input vector has a corresponding weight matrix, and then multiply each input by its weights, resulting in a tensor of shape `[b, m]`.

In normal Python I suspect this would look something like

`output_list = [matmul(w, i) for w, i in zip(weight_list, input_list)]`

but haven't been able to find a Tensorflow analogue; is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.matmul` can do a matmul over each training example in the batch. But you need to deal with some dimensions problem to achieve your goal.

```
import tensorflow as tf

b,n,m = 4,3,2
weight_list = tf.random.normal(shape=(b,n,m))
input_list = tf.random.normal(shape=(b,n))
result = tf.squeeze(tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(input_list,axis=1),weight_list))
print(result.shape)

(4, 2)
```